# How to download pdf from a pdf.js viewer window which has download option disabled?

Tags: pdf, download, website, javascript

Having a really hard time downloading a pdf from a pdf.js viewer window which has download option disabled in its website, i perhaps think that maybe by some inspect element tools i can get till it but i have aldready tried the Inspect Element > Network > find a pdf or get.php but that doesn't work. I also tried to display:none download button to display:inline download button but all it does is display the download button and whenever clicking on it, it gives no response, i also tried to replicate the website by wget but unfortunately the site has a login portal. Please help.

Comment: Do you have permission from the website owner to download the file?

Comment: Trying to circumvent the website's security settings seems inappropriate here. That said, if they allow you to *view* the PDF, you can always make screenshots or print the page, *even to PDF*, and use OCR to get the text contents.

Comment: I do have the permission from the head managment to download the file, but they do not seem to have technical knowledge and the person working on our IT Department is on a leave so i need to figure out a way to download it somehow. I cannot screenshot every single page and make a pdf out of it as the original pdf has about 400 pages. Please let me know if you have a shorter way available.

Comment: @KJ does that mean there is no way for downlading the file rather than contacting the owner? i do have the permission from the owner to download the pdf but they do not have the technical knowledge, and the person assigned to the website job is on a leave. I am fully authorised to download the pdf in any way possible.

Comment: @KJ I think i have no option rather than waiting now then, thanks for the respnse.

Answer (score 0):

If it were simple to do this, there would be no point to their being an option to prevent download. It isn't a "prevent download unless the person really wants it" button, and authorization assumes the owner has the file in some other place they can get it to you. No, serving the file using this viewer and preventing its download will prevent you from downloading it, if the system is working properly.

Protections are not protections if they are easily circumvented, or if they are not continually improved to patch or remove methods of unauthorized access.

I know that is likely frustrating to hear, but it is the nature of protected systems.

A properly running pdf.js will not allow you to download the file through it when that option is disable. We can only assume this is the case. The owner who set that option must use the other means at their disposal to retrieve the file and deliver it to you. That is their responsibility, particularly considering that they set that option to begin with.